# How does Grover's Quantum Sorting avoid reading the list?

Tags: algorithms, sorting, quantum-computing

It is well known now that [Grover's quantum algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm) can **SORT** a database of $N$ entries in $O(\sqrt{N})$ time. How can an algorithm work without reading through the list of entries which needs $O(N)$ operation. How does Grover's algorithm avoid reading the list? Is there a special representation that can be used classically as well? I understand any such representation will not help the classical case. However I am curious to understand how Grover avoids reading the list?

Comment: Like many quantum algorithms, Grover's algorithm is probabilistic in the sense that it gives the correct answer with high probability. The probability of failure can be decreased by repeating the algorithm.

Comment: @VitalijZadneprovskij My question is different. How does Grover avoid reading the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list (or database) is given implicitly by an "oracle" function, which is called $\Theta(\sqrt{N})$ times throughout the algorithm. Suppose for example you're looking for a divisor of some number $N$. Then the function could map $k \leq \sqrt{N}$ to *true* if $k$ is a non-trivial divisor of $N$, and *false* otherwise. Grover's algorithm will then find a non-trivial divisor of $N$ in time $\tilde{O}(\sqrt[4]{N})$ instead of the usual $\tilde{O}(\sqrt{N})$ (note that better algorithms are available in this case, even for a classical computer).

Comment: Hmmm could you delve into the the oracle please? Can it be described classically and intuitively and if possible formally and mathematically?

Comment: The oracle is an arbitrary function. When you run Grover's algorithm, you plug in the code of your oracle function into the algorithm.

Comment: This sounds a bit like magic mirror to me. Is there a good reference that talks about what properties the oracle should possess mathematically in order to represent the database of N entries so that Grover could design such an algorithm?

Comment: The oracle is just an ordinary function. Grover's algorithm contains a "hook" to the function, which it calls $\Theta(\sqrt{N})$ times, rather than $\Theta(N)$ times as in the classical algorithm. Nothing magical about it. It is misleading to state that the function represents a "database". Rather the database is defined by the graph of the function, and so it is far from being arbitrary.

Comment: Thankyou. What would be a good reference with the least quantum stuff?

Comment: There is no quantum stuff at all. The "oracle" is just a function. Popular accounts could say that Grover's algorithm can "search a list" (certainly not sort it), but that's very misleading. It can find a solution for an equation $f(x) = 1$ for a boolean function with domain of size $N$ using $\Theta(\sqrt{N})$ applications of $f$. That's all.

Comment: What was your resource to learn this stuff?

Comment: The Wikipedia article on Grover's algorithm.

Comment: For a popular discussion of oracles for Grover's search, see http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~imarkov/pubs/jour/cise05-grov.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The premise of your question is faulty.  Grover's algorithm can not sort a list in $O(\sqrt{N})$ time.  Informally, Grover's algorithm is for *searching* a list, not *sorting* a list.  Beware that "searching a list" is an informal description of what Grover's algorithm does, that should not be taken too seriously; what Grover's algorithm actually does is a little different, and you can find [a good description on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm).

Comment: I got that from Yuval's answer.

Comment: Do you know how long does it take to sort?

Comment: @JAS, you should post a new question for that, as that's a totally different question.  But make sure you read the help center first.